# Structure for C program to connect SQL Server on linux machine

Tags: c

Structure for C program to connect SQL Server on linux machine.
There are some *dbfile, dbstatus etc.. which are part of existing sybase structure DBPROCESS
and are being used across C programs.We are using ODBC Driver which connect to SQL Server using SQLHDBC.
Structure SQLHDBC doesnt have below structure variables.We are assuming that there would be similar structure for SQL Server in C for connectivity. 
Can anybody suggest where we can get the structure for C program to connect SQL Server similar to the one available for sybase below.

```
struct dbprocess
{
    struct servbuf  *dbfile;        /* dataserver connection */
    DBINT           dbstatus;       /* status field for dbprocess */
    BYTE            dbtoken;        /* current dataserver token */
    DBSTRING        *dbcmdbuf;      /* command buffer */
    int             dbcurcmd;       /* number of the current cmd results */
    DBINT           dbprocid;       /* procid, if any, of the current cmd */
    DBCOLINFO       *dbcols;        /* linked list of column information */
    DBALTHEAD       *dbalts;        /* linked list of alt column info */
    DBROW           *dbfirstdata;   /* doubly linked list of returned row data
    DBROW           *dbcurdata;     /* current row in dbfirstdata */
    DBROW           *dblastdata;    /* last row in dbfirstdata, usually dbcurdata */
    DBOFF           *dboffsets;     /* list of offsets and controls in dbcmdbuf*/
    int             dboffadjust;    /* adjustment factor for offsets */
    DBSMALLINT      dbcuroffset;    /* active offset for results */
    DBOPTION        *dbopts;
    DBSTRING        *dboptcmd;      /* option string to send to server */
    DBINFO          *dbmsgs;        /* linked list of info and error messages*/
    DBINFO          *dbcurmsg;      /* last message read by dbgetmsg() */
    DBMSG           *dbsrvmsg;      /* Contents of the MSG datastream */
    BYTE            *dbcurparam;    /* Previous MSG parameter */
    BYTE            dbcurparlen;    /* Length of previous parameter */
    DBDONE          dbdone;         /* done information */
};
typedef struct dbprocess DBPROCESS;
```

Thanks in advance.
Prashanthi

Comment: I don't know unixODBC but on Windows ODBC you wouldn't have all of that information in a single structure: you'd get the relevant subsets of it from each command you run, and there are other differences e.g. data is returned as a cursor you iterate through rather than a linked list already loaded into a structure for you.

Comment: Do we have any relevant header file (e.g. sql.h,sqlext.h.) for connecting to SQL Server similar to the particular structure of DBPROCESS for Sybase?